# Pinch Gesture in .NET MAUI: Why does the Pinch event stop working after multiple interactions?

Tags: maui

I'm developing a .NET MAUI application and encountering issues with the reliability of the Pinch gesture within a GraphicsView. After multiple interactions with the Pinch gesture, the event triggers sporadically or eventually stops triggering altogether.

I'm using the following XAML code:

```
<GraphicsView x:Name="graphicsView">
    <GraphicsView.GestureRecognizers>
        <PinchGestureRecognizer PinchUpdated="OnPinchUpdated" />
    </GraphicsView.GestureRecognizers>
</GraphicsView>
```

And in the code-behind, I have this event handler:

```
private void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                startScale = graphicsView.Scale;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
                currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
                currentScale = Math.Max(1, currentScale);
                graphicsView.Scale = currentScale;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                startScal = currentScale;
                break;
        }
    }
```

After several interactions, the OnPinchUpdated event is only called sporadically and eventually stops altogether. When I remove the line graphicsView.Scale = currentScale;, the Pinch gesture continues to work.

What might be causing this behavior? Are there best practices or changes in logic that could ensure the reliable functioning of the Pinch gesture without it failing after multiple interactions?

I tried using

```
graphicsView.ScaleTo(currentScale)
```

Comment: Have you referred to the [Add a pinch gesture recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pinch) and tried the sample code?

Comment: Could you please share more code about the xaml?

Comment: The code only calculates the scale factor and apply it to the graphicsview. The translationX and translationY should also be considered. Also, the scale factor should apply to the whole Content of the page.

Comment: Yes thanks. The Code doesnt Affect the content itself.

Comment: The [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithgestures-pinchgesture/) provides a good example of how to handle pinch gesture to enlarge or shrink the image. You may refer to it. If you have any questions, please provide more code in xaml about how you manage the UI, which may influence the effect of the pinch gesture.